# Адрес процедуры (не метода)

Tags: delphi

Собсно сабж, есть класс

```
TSomeClass   = class
  onMyEvent  : Procedure(t:TObject);
  Procedure MyProc;
end;
```

и Код:

```
Procedure SomeProc(t:TObject);
Begin
end;

Procedure TSomeClass.MyProc;
Begin
  onMyEvent(p);//P- TObject;
end;
//////////////
Var
  MySomeClass: TSomeClass
Begin
  MySomeClass.onMyEvent:=SomeProc;
  MySomeClass.MyProc;
end.
```

Все бы было хорошо. но ведь процедура может быть не установлена.. как отследить такой момент?

```
Procedure TSomeClass.MyProc;
Begin
  if onMyEvent<>nil then //Так не выходит. 
  //if Pointer(onMyEvent)<>nil then //Тоже не выходит 
  //ругается что не достаточно параметров;
  onMyEvent;
end;
```

Comment: `onMyEvent: TNotifyEvent` так будет работать

Comment: не будет так работать) учите паскали...
TNotifyEvent - метод, у меня процедура.

Comment: да, не сразу прочитал ваш заголовок. сбило с толку `onMyEvent`.

Comment: TNotifyEvent - не метод, а процедурный тип
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
в официальной справке рекомендуют проверять так ка предложил Вам Alouette

Comment: of object; - метод!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно проверяют так:

```
if assigned(onMyEvent) then
begin
  onMyEvent;
end;
```

Comment: тогда уж так `if assigned(@onMyEvent) then...` и то врядли.

Comment: Спасиб) до этого всегда делал Pointer и Call

Comment: Оба варианта рабочие...